# sencha touch nested 'hasMany' associations

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.2

Scenario

**Lets go classic User hasMany Order hasMany Productos.**

1.- Create and load a UserStore

2.- Get first record

3.- This record has a ordersStore (auto-generated, so far as expected)

4.- Then get first record of ordersStore, look for productosStore **BUT THERE IS NONE**        although a look to raw config shows array products.

**So my question is: ARE SECOND LEVEL HASMANY ASSOCIATIONS GENERATING A STORE AUTOMATICALLY IN THE MODEL THAT THE ASSOCIATION IS DEFINED ?**

any known issues for Sencha Touch 2.2.1 regarding this?

Dummy demo code:

```
Ext.define('Myapp.model.User', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
    config : {
        fields       : [
            {
                name : 'name',
                type : 'string'
            }
        ],
        hasMany : [
            {
                model   : 'Myapp.model.Order',
                name    : 'orders',
                associationsKey : 'orders'
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('Myapp.model.Order', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
    config : {
        fields       : [
            {
                name : 'orderName',
                type : 'string'
            }
        ],
        hasMany : [
            {
                model   : 'Myapp.model.Product',
                name    : 'products',
                associationsKey : 'products'
            }
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('Myapp.model.Product', {
    extend  : 'Ext.data.Model',
    config : {
        fields       : [
            {
                name : 'productName',
                type : 'string'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: I invoke to mighty @Saki :)

Comment: very interesting: http://extjs-tutorials.blogspot.mx/2012/05/extjs-hasmany-relationships-rules.html DOES THIS MEAN IT DOESN'T WORK IF A USERSTORE COMES INTO PLAY ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
hasMany : [
            {
                model   : 'Myapp.model.Product',
                name    : 'products',
                associationsKey : 'products',
                autoLoad : true  // < -----------THIS ONE MAKED IT
            }
        ]
```

thanks @_ErnestoR